# Getting an Assertion Failed error after integrating Ember with Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js

I created a small inventory app in Ember, and followed a tutorial on adding Rails 4 as a persistence  layer:
http://pixelhandler.com/blog/2013/09/24/scaffold-for-a-browser-app-built-with-ember-js-and-rails/

But now I am getting the following error in the console:

```
Assertion failed: You included Ember Data but didn't define App.Store
```

The pages load fine, and it renders my index.erb and application.html.erb, but I get nothing from my ember bits rendered.

I am at a bit of a loss on how to troubleshoot this issue. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

***Update:***
I am also getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Attempting to register an unknown factory: `store:main`
```

and I do have App.Store defined in store.js:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
   adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create()
});
```

Comment: Was this ever resolved and you managed to get it working? Having a similar issue now.

Answer (score 9):

I think that you are using the Ember Data 0.13 or 0.14. In these versions you need to declare the store property. Like this:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter
})
```

> Update: I am also getting this error:
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Attempting to register an unknown factory:
>   `store:main`

Make sure that your `App.Store = ...` declaration comes **before** the ember-data script.

Comment: Ah, I see that you do are not using .create() as I am, but when I remove it I still get the same error.

Comment: It worked for me with the declaration after the ember-data script.